# Finding rows with same id but different date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Consider below table tbl:

```
id    date
1     2016
1     2017
2     2017
2     2017
3     2016
3     2017
4     2018
5     2018
```

How can I get only rows with same id but different date.

Right now I can only get ids with more than 1 count like so:

```
select id, date
from tbl
group by id
having count(id)>1
```

How can I only get id 1 and 3 along with date?

Comment: I hope the table has more columns and a `UNIQUE` constraint defined and it's not just what you show here ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an `AGGREGATE` function like `MIN` or `MAX`.

If you only want one record per ID, you have to choose which date you want.
The first (MIN) or the latest (MAX).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

**^^Above information is not what was requested.**

Edited per clarification in comments:  Just use the HAVING to identify which ID values have more than one date, then apply that to a new SELECT.

```
SELECT id, Date
FROM tbl
WHERE id IN
    (
        select id 
        from tbl
        group by id
        having count(distinct date)>1
    )
```

Comment: I want both the rows. I idea is to get all the ids with same number but with different dates.

Comment: Understood, edited answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. This is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 5):

A few more ways to get the same result:

First, using `min(date) < max(date)` as the `HAVING` condition - instead of the `count(distinct date) > 1`. Perhaps slightly more efficient:

```
select id, date
from tbl
where id in 
      ( select id
        from tbl
        group by id
        having min(date) < max(date)
      ) ;
```

or with a `JOIN`:

```
select t.id, t.date
from tbl as t
     join 
      ( select id
        from tbl
        group by id
        having min(date) < max(date)
      ) as g
      on g.id = t.id ;
```

and one converting the `IN` to a correlated `EXISTS` subquery. Bonus, we can remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
select id, date
from tbl as t
where exists
      ( select 1
        from tbl as t2
        where t.id = t2.id
          and t.date <> t2.date
      ) ;
```

Another that uses window functions:

```
select id, date
from
  ( select id, date,
           diff_dates = case when min(date) over (partition by id)
                                < max(date) over (partition by id)
                             then 1
                        end 
    from tbl
  ) as d
where diff_dates = 1 ;
```

and last, one for the obfuscation contest:

```
select id, date from tbl
except
select id, min(date) from tbl group by id
intersect
select id, max(date) from tbl group by id ;
```

Test in **[dbfiffle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04569c5bec170c8e7c7500f551069289)**.

Answer (score 2):

You should count , as you did, and count distinct per date

```
SELECT T.id,T.date
FROM Table1 AS T
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT C.id 
          ,Count(id) as count_id
          ,Count(Distinct date) as count_Distinct_Records
      FROM Table1 AS C
      WHERE C.id = T.id
      GROUP BY id) AS CA
WHERE
  CA.count_id > 1
  AND count_Distinct_Records > 1
```

output here:

```
id  date
1   2016
1   2017
3   2016
3   2017
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8267cf2e11dc07820a2e965e0e324507)

Answer (score -2):

Try this, replace table name

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ) RowNum, date
 FROM dbo.table
```

Comment: That won't give the sought answer.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

select id,date from table2 group by id,date